# What is the PHP config ini files prefix good for?

Tags: php, debian

Out of nothing but curiosity:

Why are the symlinks in `/etc/php5/conf.d` prefixed with either "10" or "20"?
E.g. `20-pdo_mysql.ini` and `20-curl.ini`

I'm running Debian and installed PHP from the dotdeb repository.

Comment: I think it has to do with the order the `.ini` files are executed in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically it specifies the order in which the INI files are loaded when conf.d/*.ini is included.

Comment: In which case could that be useful?

Comment: @ThomasJensen: multiple (possibly 3rd party) packages settings different values, last one wins. It doesn't have to be a per-subcategory config.